# Comparing two arrays and printing results as a collection of a class

Tags: object-oriented, array, vba, excel

This is really my first time using a class and I originally wrote it without the class and without refactoring.

This is to take two inputs (csv), place the data in arrays and then compare the arrays. Both inputs have the exact same structure e.g.

[image]

It returns any matches that have the same `C,D,E,W` and gives the header (Var) as well as the previous and current values. I didn't name the headers.

I don't have rubberduck installed.

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Delta_Var()
    Const PROMPT As String = "The Results sheet already exists. Do you want to continue and overwrite the data?"
    Dim SheetCheck As Boolean
    SheetCheck = GetResultSheet(PROMPT)
    If Not SheetCheck Then Exit Sub
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim originalDataArray As Variant
    originalDataArray = GetData(1)
    If IsEmpty(originalDataArray) Then GoTo Cleanup
    Dim newDataArray As Variant
    newDataArray = GetData(0)
    If IsEmpty(newDataArray) Then GoTo Cleanup
    
    Dim resultSheet As Worksheet
    Set resultSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Results")
    ModelResults
    
    Dim originalRecords() As String
    ReDim originalRecords(1 To UBound(originalDataArray))
    Dim newRecords() As String
    ReDim newRecords(1 To UBound(newDataArray))
    
    originalRecords() = PopulateDataArray(originalDataArray)
    newRecords = PopulateDataArray(newDataArray)

    Dim matchOriginalToNew() As Variant
    ReDim matchOriginalToNew(1 To UBound(newRecords), 1 To 2)
    matchOriginalToNew = MatchRecords(newRecords, originalRecords)
    
    PopulateResults originalDataArray, newDataArray, matchOriginalToNew, resultSheet
    resultSheet.Columns.AutoFit
    resultSheet.Columns.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
Cleanup:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Private Function MatchRecords(ByRef newRecords() As String, ByRef originalRecords() As String) As Variant
    Dim matchArray As Variant
    ReDim matchArray(1 To UBound(newRecords), 1 To 2)
    Dim recordIndex As Long
    Dim arrayIndex As Long
    Dim matchCounter As Long
    matchCounter = 1
    For recordIndex = LBound(newRecords) To UBound(newRecords)
        For arrayIndex = LBound(originalRecords) To UBound(originalRecords)
            If newRecords(recordIndex) = originalRecords(arrayIndex) Then
                matchArray(matchCounter, 1) = arrayIndex
                matchArray(matchCounter, 2) = recordIndex
                matchCounter = matchCounter + 1
            End If
        Next
    Next
    MatchRecords = matchArray
End Function

Private Function PopulateDataArray(ByVal dataArray As Variant) As String()
    Dim arrayRecord() As String
    ReDim arrayRecord(1 To UBound(dataArray))
    Dim arrayIndex As Long
    For arrayIndex = LBound(dataArray) To UBound(dataArray)
        arrayRecord(arrayIndex) = dataArray(arrayIndex, 3) & dataArray(arrayIndex, 4) & dataArray(arrayIndex, 5) & dataArray(arrayIndex, 58)
    Next
    PopulateDataArray = arrayRecord
End Function

Private Function GetData(ByVal first As Boolean) As Variant
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim fileName As String
    If first Then
        Dim originalBook As Workbook
        Dim originalSheet As Worksheet
        fileName = File_Picker(True)
        On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
        Set originalBook = Workbooks.Open(fileName)
        Set originalSheet = originalBook.Sheets(1)
        Dim originalDataRange As Range
        lastRow = originalSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        GetData = originalSheet.Range(originalSheet.Cells(1, 1), originalSheet.Cells(lastRow, 58))
        originalBook.Close
    Else:
        Dim newBook As Workbook
        Dim newSheet As Worksheet
        fileName = File_Picker(False)
        Set newBook = Workbooks.Open(fileName)
        Set newSheet = newBook.Sheets(1)
        Dim newDataRange As Range
        lastRow = newSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        GetData = newSheet.Range(newSheet.Cells(1, 1), newSheet.Cells(lastRow, 58))
        newBook.Close
    End If
    Exit Function
ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "you've cancelled"
End Function

Private Function GetResultSheet(ByVal PROMPT As String) As Boolean
    Const RESULT_SHEET_NAME As String = "Results"
    Dim continue As VbMsgBoxResult
    If WorksheetExists(RESULT_SHEET_NAME) Then
        continue = MsgBox(PROMPT, vbYesNo)
        If continue = vbNo Then
            GetResultSheet = False
            Exit Function
        Else:
            GetResultSheet = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    End If
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Worksheets.Count - 1).Name = "Results"
    GetResultSheet = True
End Function

Function WorksheetExists(sName As String) As Boolean
    WorksheetExists = Evaluate("ISREF('" & sName & "'!A1)")
End Function

Private Sub ModelResults()
    Const HEADER_ROW As Long = 1
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Results")
        .UsedRange.Clear
        .Cells(HEADER_ROW, 1) = "Subject"
        .Cells(HEADER_ROW, 2) = "Folder"
        .Cells(HEADER_ROW, 3) = "Occured_on"
        .Cells(HEADER_ROW, 4) = "Timepoint"
        .Cells(HEADER_ROW, 5) = "VAR"
        .Cells(HEADER_ROW, 6) = "Previous Value"
        .Cells(HEADER_ROW, 7) = "New Value"
        .Range("A1:G1").Font.Bold = True
    End With
End Sub

Private Function File_Picker(ByVal original As Boolean) As String
    Dim version As String
    Dim workbookName As String
    If original Then
        version = "original"
        Else: version = "new"
    End If
    Dim selectFile As FileDialog
    MsgBox "Please select the file with your " & version & " data."
    Set selectFile = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
    With selectFile
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Title = "Select the file with your " & version & " data."
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "Excel Document", ("*.csv, *.xls")
        .InitialView = msoFileDialogViewDetails
        If .Show = -1 Then
            Dim selectedItem
            For Each selectedItem In selectFile.SelectedItems
                File_Picker = selectedItem
            Next selectedItem
        End If
    End With
    Set selectFile = Nothing
End Function

Private Sub PopulateResults(ByVal originalDataArray As Variant, ByVal newDataArray As Variant, ByVal matchOriginalToNew As Variant, ByVal resultSheet As Worksheet)
    Dim records As Collection
    Set records = New Collection
    Dim result As RecordResult
    
    Dim recordIndex As Long
    Dim originalIndex As Long
    Dim newIndex As Long
    Dim columnIndex As Long
    Dim i As Long
    
    For recordIndex = LBound(matchOriginalToNew) To UBound(matchOriginalToNew)
        originalIndex = matchOriginalToNew(recordIndex, 1)
        newIndex = matchOriginalToNew(recordIndex, 2)
        For columnIndex = 6 To 56
            If originalDataArray(originalIndex, columnIndex) <> newDataArray(newIndex, columnIndex) Then
               Set result = New RecordResult
                result.Subject = originalDataArray(originalIndex, 3)
                result.Folder = originalDataArray(originalIndex, 4)
                result.Occurence = originalDataArray(originalIndex, 5)
                result.Timepoint = originalDataArray(originalIndex, 58)
                result.Var = originalDataArray(1, columnIndex)
                result.OriginalValue = originalDataArray(originalIndex, columnIndex)
                result.NewValue = newDataArray(newIndex, columnIndex)
                records.Add result
               End If
           Next
    Next
    
    With resultSheet
        For i = 1 To records.Count
            resultSheet.Cells(i + 1, 1) = records(i).Subject
            resultSheet.Cells(i + 1, 2) = records(i).Folder
            resultSheet.Cells(i + 1, 3) = records(i).Occurence
            resultSheet.Cells(i + 1, 4) = records(i).Timepoint
            resultSheet.Cells(i + 1, 5) = records(i).Var
            resultSheet.Cells(i + 1, 6) = records(i).OriginalValue
            resultSheet.Cells(i + 1, 7) = records(i).NewValue
        Next
    End With
   
End Sub
```

---

#### And the Class Module `RecordResult`

```
Option Explicit

Private pSubject As String
Private pFolder As String
Private pOccurence As Date
Private pTimepoint As String
Private pVar As String
Private pOriginalValue As Double
Private pNewValue As Double
Public Property Get Subject() As String
    Subject = pSubject
End Property

Public Property Get Folder() As String
    Folder = pFolder
End Property
Public Property Get Occurence() As Date
    Occurence = pOccurence
End Property

Public Property Get Timepoint() As String
    Timepoint = pTimepoint
End Property

Public Property Get Var() As String
    Var = pVar
End Property

Public Property Get OriginalValue() As Double
    OriginalValue = pOriginalValue
End Property

Public Property Get NewValue() As Double
    NewValue = pNewValue
End Property

Public Property Let Subject(Value As String)
    pSubject = Value
End Property

Public Property Let Folder(Value As String)
    pFolder = Value
End Property
Public Property Let Occurence(Value As Date)
    pOccurence = Value
End Property

Public Property Let Timepoint(Value As String)
    pTimepoint = Value
End Property

Public Property Let Var(Value As String)
    pVar = Value
End Property

Public Property Let OriginalValue(Value As Double)
    pOriginalValue = Value
End Property

Public Property Let NewValue(Value As Double)
    pNewValue = Value
End Property
```

Comment: I know the site is about giving advice on code, however I'd appreciate to know you specific question. Do you have any (performance) issue with it? Or would like to know best practices on classes?...

Comment: @MátéJuhász Probably whether I can use the class more efficiently. I don't really have any future need for the macro, but I usually refer back to my questions when I write new ones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Naming

***No need to use different naming for Class modules than regular modules***, so no need for `pSubject` when it can just be `subject`.

Additionally, passing arguments called `Value` isn't necessary, you can use regular variable names, as well as pass then `ByVal`:

```
Option Explicit

Private testSubject As String
Private testingFolder As String
Private occurenceDate As Date
Private pointInTime As String
Private testVariableName As String
Private originalValue As Double
Private newValue As Double
Public Property Get Subject() As String
    Subject = testSubject
End Property

Public Property Get Folder() As String
    Folder = testingFolder
End Property
Public Property Get Occurence() As Date
    Occurence = occurenceDate
End Property

Public Property Get Timepoint() As String
    Timepoint = pointInTime
End Property

Public Property Get Var() As String
    Var = testVariableName
End Property

Public Property Get originalValue() As Double
    originalValue = originalValue
End Property

Public Property Get newValue() As Double
    newValue = newValue
End Property

Public Property Let Subject(ByVal subjectInput As String)
    testSubject = subjectInput
End Property

Public Property Let Folder(ByVal folderInput As String)
    testingFolder = folderInput
End Property
Public Property Let Occurence(ByVal occuredOn As Date)
    occurenceDate = occuredOn
End Property

Public Property Let Timepoint(ByVal timePointInput As String)
    pointInTime = timePointInput
End Property

Public Property Let Var(ByVal varName As String)
    testVariableName = varName
End Property

Public Property Let originalValue(ByVal originalData As Double)
    originalValue = originalData
End Property

Public Property Let newValue(ByVal newData As Double)
    newValue = newData
End Property
```